# Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "value"

Tags: xml

I want to add multiple labels to a gmail filter, so I have downloaded the xml file of the filter and adapted it to include all labels I want. When I saved it and tried to import it again on gmail, I get an error 'Could not understand the file'. When clicking on it, it says 
mailFilters.xml:25:37: Error parsing file: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "value".

As I understood from other posts on this forum, it means that somewhere an open quote should be missing after a "value" element type. I have searched through all of my code, but cannot find any missing. Am I missing something or is there another error going on? Thanks for your help

Here is my code
https://www.evernote.com/l/AlJORptCs-FGMo2Uwb7onYFwGWR4JfqgJ3U

Comment: Strange enough it copied wrongly when I copied the code from TextEdit to my post. Since I cannot copy it completely in the comment (where it does show up correctly), I just link to the code here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AlJORptCs-FGMo2Uwb7onYFwGWR4JfqgJ3U

Answer (score 1):

Check this line and similar

```
<apps:property name='label' value='‘Evernote'/copywriting_about’/>
```

It has non-matching quotes. Try to change it to this

```
<apps:property name='label' value='‘Evernote’/copywriting_about'/>
```

Update:

This line has a problem too

```
    <apps:property name='label' value=‘competition’/>
```

Only ' and " are allowed as quote symbols for attributes, and ‘ is not one of them

Answer (score 1):

May be you have forget to put a single or double quote either at starting or to end in your class bean definition.

```
<bean id=faculty" class="com.nareshit.app.Faculty" autowire="constructor">
</bean>
```

so in the first bean definition we have not putted the double quote earlier giving the bean id,

```
<bean id="faculty" class="com.nareshit.app.Faculty" autowire="constructor">
</bean>
```

hope it will help anyone, thanks.